# Has any system been placed in orbit using horizontal-launch?

Tags: launch

Most systems, that I am aware of, use vertical-launch but horizontal-launch has been envisioned for many years. Has horizontal-launch ever been successful?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the event of plane based launches. Pegasus is the most well known such system.

Comment: Did the Pegasus achieve orbit?

Comment: Yes, 42 launches, 3 complete failures, 3 partial failures. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(rocket)#Launch_history

Comment: Cosmic. Why this didn't got to see XXL?

Comment: There will be another 'launch' of Pegasus in November, so you can see it in action.